Isn't Schopenhauer a sophist?
Sophists are philosophers who reduce any philosophical attempts as either a simple rhetorical exercise or a subjective and private enterprise. Protagoras and Gorgias are seen as sophists, and their philosophy as relativist.
Schopenhauer wrote a treatise The Art of Being Right, where he analyzes the methods that people use to win intellectual debates.
But with the fact that Schopenhauer defended a philosophy of extreme subjectivism (therefore leading to relativism), and with this very book which cynically analyzes how people wins debates just by rhetorical means, I would be surprise that Schopenhauer is not considered a typical sophist.

Schopenhauer is best known for his treatise The Art of Being Right... What?? World as Will and Idea is universally acepted as his magnum opus. If you take a side note pamphlet he wrote in pique and define him from that you can prove anything you like

"Schopenhauer defended a philosophy of extreme subjectivity (therefore leading to relativism)" is a rather idiosyncratic characterization. He is an objective idealist on standard accounts, and famous for pessimism, not relativism. Writing books on rhetoric and debates is not uncommon among philosophers either, Aristotle wrote one, among others. It does not make them sophists.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Well... yes, sorry. I corrected!

@Rushi My bad. I corrected. Thank you

Wow, sarcasm in Philosophy. Who would have thought? :-)
